# node-gyp build error causes yarn install to fail

Tags: module, node-gyp

yarn install fails with the following stack trace. Been trying to debug this for days with no success.

i have tried everything that was suggested in other posts but nothing helped

```
yarn install v1.22.19
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > apollo-server-express@3.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "express@^4.17.1".
warning " > ts-loader@9.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0".
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
[4/4] Rebuilding all packages...
[-/7] ⠄ waiting...
[7/7] ⠄ redis-fast-driver
[-/7] ⠄ waiting...
[-/7] ⠄ waiting...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "C:\\Users\\Saba\\Source\\Repos\\api.bitnet.ge\\node_modules\\redis-fast-driver: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: C:\\Users\\Saba\\Source\\Repos\\api.bitnet.ge\\node_modules\\redis-fast-driver
Output:
C:\\Users\\Saba\\Source\\Repos\\api.bitnet.ge\\node_modules\\redis-fast-driver>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\node-gyp-bin\\\\..\\..\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js\" rebuild )  else (node \"\" rebuild )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@18.16.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.4 found at \"C:\\Users\\Saba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe\"
gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.6.33815.320) found at:
gyp info find VS \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\\Users\\Saba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\gyp\\\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\Saba\\\\Source\\\\Repos\\\\api.bitnet.ge\\\\node_modules\\\\redis-fast-driver\\\\build\\\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\Saba\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.16.1\\\\include\\\\node\\\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\Saba\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.16.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\Saba\\\\\\\\AppData\\\\\\\\Local\\\\\\\\node-gyp\\\\\\\\Cache\\\\\\\\18.16.1\\\\\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\Saba\\\\Source\\\\Repos\\\\api.bitnet.ge\\\\node_modules\\\\redis-fast-driver',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\Saba\\\\Source\\\\Repos\\\\api.bitnet.ge\\\\node_modules\\\\redis-fast-driver\\\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the \"-m\" switch.

  hiredis.c
C:\\Users\\Saba\\Source\\Repos\\api.bitnet.ge\\node_modules\\redis-fast-driver\\deps\\hiredis\\hiredis.c(37,10): fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory [C:\\Users\\Saba\\Source\\Repos\\api.bitnet.ge\\node_modules\\redis-fast-driver\\build\\deps\\hiredis.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\" \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\bin\\\\node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\\Users\\Saba\\Source\\Repos\\api.bitnet.ge\\node_modules\\redis-fast-driver
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 44.60s
```

There were many other errors; it required Python and Visual Studio. I installed them, and those errors got fixed, but this still remains.

It works fine on Mac, but on Windows, this happens.